# Prove that a rectangle or square in metric space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Review of proof would be appreciated.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $R=\{(x,y): \ \mid x\mid \leq A, \ \mid y \mid \leq B \}$ be a rectangle contained in $X$ (Note: $A=B$ is the special case where the rectangle is a square. Thus, this proof applies to squares as well).

We need to show that all limit points for $R$ are contained within $R \implies R$  is closed. We show this via contradiction. For sake of contradiction, suppose there exists a limit point $\ (x',y') \in X;$ $(x',y') \not\in R$ such that a sequence $\{x_n,y_n\} \subseteq R$ converges to $(x',y')$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{\min(\mid A-x'\mid,\mid B-y' \mid)}{2} \geq 0$ be the radius of a neighborhood $B_\epsilon(x',y')$ centered around $(x',y')$. By construction, $B_\epsilon(x',y') \not\subseteq R$, but by convergence $B_\epsilon(x',y')$ contains all but finitely many points of $\{x_n,y_n \} \implies B_\epsilon(x',y')$ contains infinitely many points of $\{x_n,y_n \}$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $R$ contains all of its limit points $\implies$ the set formed by points within AND on the bounds of any rectangle or square is a closed set.

Comment: How can a sequence of real numbers in R converge to an ordered pair in R^2?

Comment: You need a sequence of (r_n,s_n) converge to (x'y').  You are on 5he right track.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the OP so that $\{r_n\}$ is now $\{x_n,y_n\}$

Comment: Nitpick, now that you've fixed it write $\mathbb R^2$ rather than $\mathbb R$.  I'll have to get back to you if the "all but finite" is valid.  I think it is, but I don't want to steer you wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I do write $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\mathbb{R}$. The $R$ is defined to be the rectangle. Is this what you were referring to? Also, the rectangle I constructed is centered around $(0,0)$. I am having trouble writing a general version of the proof that allows the rectangle to be offset either positively or negatively in either or both of the coordinates. Can you let me know how I can do this? I understand that changing the restriction on the boundaries to $\mid x+a \mid \leq A, \mid y+b \mid \leq B$ offsets the rectangle. I am not sure how to prove that this is closed though.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  You are right.